# Ancient artifact problem Horizon Zero Dawn

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I can't seem to sell my ancient artifacts with merchants in horizon zero Dawn, they literally aren't present in my resource inventory yet it says I can't store more because I'm full, is there a way around this? It's quite frustrating

Answer (score 6):

If you are referring to the idols, and the cups, etc, they can only be sold to specific vendors. [Studious Palas](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Studious_Palas) purchases the cups from you, [Kudiv](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Kudiv) buys the Metal Flowers, and [Cantarah](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Cantarah) purchases the Banuk Figures. All of these Merchants can be found in Meridian.

These special artefacts actually *don't* count towards your current inventory, however, that allows you to carry more resources. You can instead [upgrade your inventory](https://au.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/Satchels_and_Pouches), or sell off some of your [resources](https://horizonzerodawn.fandom.com/wiki/Resources).